# What's the simplest way to return the first line of a multi-line string in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, multiline

When I say simple, I mean, within an expression, so that I can stick it in as a value in a hash without preparing it first. I'll post my solution but I'm looking for a better one that reminds me less of VB.  :)

Comment: Why the aversion to preparing it ahead of time?  It usually takes fancy mojo to work as a one-liner, which is the opposite of simple. While it's fun to figure these things out, it's rarely a good idea to use them in a real program, as the fancier you get, the harder it is to figure out later on.

Comment: It's a temporary solution.  :)  Good point though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about

```
( split /\n/, $s )[0]
```

?

You don't have to worry about \n being not cross-platform because [Perl is clever enough to take care of that](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl/pod/perlport.pod#Newlines).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!  I look forward to reading that article too, since I've had issues with linebreaks in the past, but perhaps it wasn't Perl's fault.

Comment: Well, Perl makes \n mean different things on different systems, but that doesn't mean that \n is the record separator for the input. :)

Comment: And, let's just hope that this string isn't huge :)

Comment: Good point, Brian...in this case it's not, it's just an error message.

Comment: Have you ever tried using 1 as the third parameter to split? What do you think split should do when told to produce only one element? You need to split into at least two elements, and even then, you end up with a list that still contains most of the data from the string.

Comment: You're right Brian, passing 1 as the third parameter causes the entire original string to be returned.  I shoulda read the docs more carefully.  All I can say in my defense is that that's not what *I* think split() should do.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't as simple as you like, but being simple just to be short shouldn't always be the goal.

You can open a filehandle on a string (as a scalar reference) and treat it as a file to read the first line:

```
my $string = "Fred\nWilma\Betty\n";
open my($fh), "<", \$string or die ...; # reading from the data in $string
my $first_line = <$fh>; # gives "Fred"
close $fh;
```

If you really wanted to, I guess you could reduce this to an expression:

```
$hash{$key} = do { open my($fh), "<", \$string; scalar <$fh> };
```

No matter which method you choose, you can always make a subroutine to return the first line and then use the subroutine call in your hash assignment.

```
sub gimme_first_line { ... }

$hash{$key } = gimme_first_line( \$string );
```

Comment: No, it's a string in memory. You can treat it like a file though.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read your code very carefully.  Huh, I didn't know you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

```
($str =~ /\A(.*?)$/ms)[0];
```

For large strings, this will be faster than

```
(split /\n/, $str)[0]
```

as suggested by Manni.  [Edit: removed erroneous mention of `split /\n/, $str, 1`.]

If you want to include the terminal `\n` if it is present, add `\n?` just before the closing paren in the regex.

Comment: Instead of your first suggestion, why not just `($str =~ /^(.*)/)[0];`?

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: You can even get rid of the `^` in your solution. Either way it is more concise than mine, but harder to understand because it relies on the reader of the code being aware that `.` does not match a `\n` in the absence of `/s`. For 5 more characters, my code makes the semantics difficult to misunderstand.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this morning that the `^` is superfluous.  Honestly, I wasn't able to follow much of what yours was doing without looking everything up, but that was mainly due to a lack of knowledge on my part.  I wouldn't have even thought to _use_ a regex for this task.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($s, 0, index($s, $/) > -1 ? index($s, $/) || () )
```