# regex split string at first line break

Tags: php, regex

I would like to split a string at the first line break, instead of the first blank line

'`/^(.*?)\r?\n\r?\n(.*)/s'` (first blank line)

So for instance, if I have:

> $str = '2099 test\nAre you sure you
>   want to continue\n some other string
>   here...';

```
match[1] = '2099 test'
match[2] = 'Are you sure you want to continue\n some other string here...'
```

Comment: One more question, is it possible to do it as well at the second break line instead of the first one?

Answer (score 13):

`preg_split()` has a limit parameter you can take to your advantage. You could just simply do:

```
$lines = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $str, 2);
```

Comment: +1 for using string manipulation instead of regex. Almost always better when possible.

Comment: Does not work. You are asking preg_split to return an array of size 1.

Comment: Noticed the mistake myself just now. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$str = "2099 test\nAre you sure you want to continue\n some other string here...";

$match = explode("\n",$str, 2);
print_r($match);


?>
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2099 test
    [1] => Are you sure you want to continue
 some other string here...
)
```

explode's last parameter is the number of elements you want to split the string into.

Answer (score 1):

Normally just remove on `\r?\n`:

```
'/^(.*?)\r?\n(.*)/s'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split` as:

```
$arr = preg_split("/\r?\n/",$str,2);
```

[**See it on Ideone**](http://www.ideone.com/JmflC)

Answer (score 1):

First line break:

```
$match = preg_split('/\R/', $str, 2);
```

First blank line:

```
$match = preg_split('/\R\R/', $str, 2);
```

Handles all the various ways of doing line breaks.

Also there was a question about splitting on the 2nd line break. Here is my implementation (maybe not most efficient... also note it replaces some line breaks with `PHP_EOL`)

```
function split_at_nth_line_break($str, $n = 1) {
    $match = preg_split('/\R/', $str, $n+1);
    if (count($match) === $n+1) {
        $rest = array_pop($match);
    }
    $match = array(implode(PHP_EOL, $match));
    if (isset($rest)) {
        $match[] = $rest;
    }
    return $match;
}

$match = split_at_nth_line_break($str, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't even need to use regex's. To get just split lines, see:

[What's the simplest way to return the first line of a multi-line string in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428065/whats-the-simplest-way-to-return-the-first-line-of-a-multi-line-string-in-perl)

Comment: All the answers there either DO use a regex, or some weird perl-specific file I/O redirection.